# Log file doesn't create in Log 4j with JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2, log4j, jboss7.x

I have created Web Application by using JSF 2.0, Log 4j 1.2.14 and JBoss 7. When I run testcase, the log file is created. And the log file can't create when I run web application.

I there is anything I need to configur, please tell me.

Comment: Thanks for your reminding me. I forgot to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this maybe can help you.

The following file[jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7#ClassLoadinginAS7-JBossDeploymentStructureFile)needs to contain the following:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally, I got it. It is very precious for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the configuration file (`log4j.xml` or `log4j.properties`) is in the classpath of the web application (in this case, in the binaries).

```
WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties
```

If you have both files (`log4.properties`, `log4j.xml`) only is considered `log4j.xml`. The first time you init or use some instance of [`org.apache.log4j.Logger`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html), log4j search the configuration file in the classpath, then the configuration is loaded.

If you want to see this process of searching and loading more closely, add the following argument to the virtual machine:

```
-Dlog4j.debug
```